# How to compute tangent of a discretized curve

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

I have a discretized curve defined by a 2D matrix $M$ where $M(i,j)=1$ means the point $(i,j)$ is on the curve. For each of these points, I want to calculate its tangent vector by fitting a polynomial thru the neighbouring points using Taylor series expansion. Could someone please let me know what is the Taylor formula in this case? Thank you.

EDIT:

1. I want to consider the 8 neighbors (3x3 matrix).
2. The curve is taken from a photo so the case of all-1 submatrix would be rare. But I'm curious how one would approach that case.
3. Cubic spline sounds great but doesn't it mean that I have to find ${a,b,c,d}$ for $y = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and then calculate derivatives? Taylor expansion seems to give me that in one go.

I'm grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: That doesn't specify the curve very well. A curve that winds back-and-forth across consecutive rows of pixels will show up as a matrix of all ones.

Comment: You may want to interpolate with a cubic spline or such. A type of piecewise polynomial fitting which could be set to give continuous derivative.

Comment: Do we know anything about the ordering of the points? Or is the matrix the only information we have?

Answer (score 1):

This is, to me, very poorly posed.

1. What do you mean be "neighbors"? In a matrix, each internal point has four neighbors, or eight if you can go diagonally.
2. What do you want to do if all nine points in a 3x3 subarray are 1?
3. If you are going to get a tangent vector, this seems to imply that there is some order to the points where the array has a 1. What is this order?
4. How is this set of points obtained? Methods used might be very different if the points are gotten sequentially or by scanning a drawing of a curve.
5. If the array entries are gotten by scanning an image of some kind, can the points look like a line with thickness greater than one?

In the past, when I have been given a series of points and required to get tangents at each point, if the points were reasonably smooth, I took the line through the preceding and following points to get the slope of the tangent. If the points were not smooth, I usually took some sort of moving average.